# Lagrangian: $\min_{\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}} \left\|\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\right\|_F^2$ s.t. $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{B}$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let us say that the optimization problem can be posed in the matrix form as given below

$\min_{\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}} \left\|\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\right\|_F^2$ s.t. $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{B}$,
where $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times K}$, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$, and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times K}$.

**Question**:

Without vectorizing the formulation, can the Lagrangian be defined as

$L(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{\Lambda}) = \left\|\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{X}\right\|_F^2 + {\rm trace}\left(\mathbf{\Lambda}^T \left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X} - \mathbf{B} \right) \right)$ ?

If not, then how to construct a Lagrangian in the matrix form? Thank you.

EDIT:
See this [How to set up Lagrangian optimization with matrix constrains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104376/how-to-set-up-lagrangian-optimization-with-matrix-constrains) .

Comment: The Lagrangian is exactly as you have defined.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.