# $\forall k \leq n, \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{j,j} \leq \sum_{j=1}^{k} \lambda_j $ for $A$ symmetric real

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

We define :

- $n \in \mathbb{N}$
- $\mathcal{B}=(e_1 \dots e_n)  $ is the initial basis orthonormal
- $A$ is the matrix symmetric real of $f$ in $\mathcal{B}$
- $\mathcal{B'}=(\epsilon_1 \dots \epsilon_n)$ is an orthonormal basis
- $\forall ~ 1\leq i \leq n, ~ f(\epsilon_i)= \lambda_i \epsilon_i$
- $\lambda_n \leq \lambda_{n-1} \dots \leq \lambda_1$

We want to prove that :
$$\forall k \leq n, \quad \sum_{j=1}^{k} a_{j,j} \leq \sum_{j=1}^{k} \lambda_j $$

Here are the following steps : $\forall ~ 1 \leq j \leq n$

1. $ a_{j,j}\leq  \sum_{i=1}^{k}  \lambda_i <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n}  \lambda_k <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2$
2. $ a_{j,j} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k} ( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k )<e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + \lambda_k $
3. We deduce the claim

---

My attempt :

1. Let $P$ the matrix of transition from $\mathcal{B}$ à $\mathcal{B'}$
   $e_j= \sum_{k=1}^{n} p_{jk} \epsilon_k \Rightarrow  p_{j,k} = <e_j,\epsilon_k>$ for all $k$

$
\begin{align*}
u(e_j) &= u( \sum_{i=1}^{n}  <e_j,\epsilon_i> \epsilon_i ) \\
   &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} <e_j,\epsilon_i> u(   \epsilon_i   ) \\     
&=  \sum_{i=1}^{n} <e_j,\epsilon_i> \lambda_i \epsilon_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} <e_j,\epsilon_i> \lambda_i \epsilon_i
\end{align*}
$

$
\begin{align*}
a_{j,j}&=<u(e_j),e_j> \\
&= <e_j,  \sum_{i=1}^{n} <e_j,\epsilon_i> \lambda_i \epsilon_i  > \\
&=  \sum_{i=1}^{n} <e_j,\epsilon_i> \lambda_i <e_j, \epsilon_i > \\
&=  \sum_{i=1}^{n}   \lambda_i <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 \\
&=  \sum_{i=1}^{k}  \lambda_i <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n}  \lambda_i <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 \\
&\leq  \sum_{i=1}^{k}  \lambda_i <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n}  \lambda_k <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 \\
\end{align*}
$

2.

$
\begin{align*}
1&=\| e_j\| \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n} <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 \\
\end{align*}
$

$
\begin{align*}
a_{j,j} &\leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}  \lambda_i <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n}  \lambda_k <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 \\
          &=  \sum_{i=1}^{k}  \lambda_i <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 +  \lambda_k ( 1- \sum_{i=1}^{k}   <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 \\
          &=  \sum_{i=1}^{k} ( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k )<e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + \lambda_k \\
\end{align*}
$

3. $ \sum_{j=1}^{k} a_{j,j} \leq \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} ( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k )<e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + \sum_{j=1}^{k} \lambda_k $
   $ 
   \begin{align*} 
   \sum_{j=1}^{k} a_{j,j} &\leq \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} ( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k )<e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + \sum_{j=1}^{k} \lambda_k \\
   &\leq \sum_{j=1}^{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} ( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k )<e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + k \lambda_k \\
   &=  \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{j=1}^{k} ( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k )<e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + k \lambda_k \\
   &=   \sum_{i=1}^{k}( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k ) \sum_{j=1}^{k} <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + k \lambda_k \\
   &\leq   \sum_{i=1}^{k}( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k ) \sum_{j=1}^{n} <e_j,\epsilon_i> ^2 + k \lambda_k \\
   &\leq   \sum_{i=1}^{k}( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k ) \| e_i\|^2 + k \lambda_k \\
   &\leq   \sum_{i=1}^{k}( \lambda_i   - \lambda_k ) +  k \lambda_k  \\
   &=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\lambda_i - (k-1)   \lambda_k  +  k \lambda_k \\
   &= \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \lambda_i + \lambda_k \\
   \end{align*}
   $

Comment: The question has typo errors, but the answer is the Ky - Fan maximum principle...

Comment: I have solved the question. Could you explicit the reference with the Ky-Fan principle ?

Comment: You may google it (plenty of references) Trace maximum principle or Ky-Fan variational maximum p. Anyway you proved what Ky-Fan has almost done in his paper on this ( variational maximum p.) If you want a precise litterature repost that. Way to go. (even for the notations are messy the proof can be more compact)

Comment: This is a standard majorization result and has extremely short proofs e.g. using Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing.  For many different proofs see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637453/maximize-mathrmtrqtcq-subject-to-qtq-i/ and consider $Q$ having the first k standard basis vectors as its columns vs the orthonormal eigenvectors  associated with $k$ largest eigenvalues of A as columns.