# How to show that $(Re\lambda_1,\dotsb,Re\lambda_n)^T$ is majorized by $(\lambda_1(H),\dotsb,\lambda_n(H))^T$?

Tags: matrices, hermitian-matrices

Suppose $\lambda_1,\dotsb,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A$. And $H,K$ are hermitian such that $A=H+iK.$ Show that $(Re\lambda_1,\dotsb,Re\lambda_n)^T$ is majorized by $(\lambda_1(H),\dotsb,\lambda_n(H))^T,$ i.e. $$\max_{1\leq i_1<\dotsb <i_k\leq n }\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_{i_j}(H)\geq \max_{1\leq i_1<\dotsb <i_k\leq n }\sum_{j=1}^k Re\lambda_{i_j}.$$ Any idea for applying Schur decomposition to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

$A= H + iK = \frac{1}{2}\big(A+A^*\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(A-A^*\big)$.

via congruence (i.e. using $Q^*AQ$ where $A=QRQ^*$ in Schur Triangularization) we can assume WLOG that $A$ is upper triangular.

Then
$\max_{1\leq i_1<\dotsb <i_k\leq n }\sum_{j=1}^k Re\lambda_{i_j}= \max_{1\leq i_1<\dotsb <i_k\leq n }\sum_{j=1}^k h_{i_j}$
i.e. maximal sum of k elements of the diagonal of $\frac{1}{2}\big(A+A^*\big)$

and this is well known to be majorized by the eigenvalues of $H$.  Reference e.g. one of the many proofs here:  [Maximize $\mathrm{tr}(Q^TCQ)$ subject to $Q^TQ=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637453/maximize-mathrmtrqtcq-subject-to-qtq-i/)