# Corollary of Schur-Horn

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

Let $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a Hermitian matrix, then $$\sum_{i=1}^k \tilde{m}_{ii} \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i,$$ for $k = 1,\dots,n-1$. Here $\tilde{m}_{11} \geq \tilde{m}_{22} \geq \cdots \geq \tilde{m}_{nn}$ are the diagonal elements of $M$ in nondecreasing order and $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $M$ in nondecreasing order.

There are lots of posts containing some information about the [Schur-Horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem) theorem, which I can see that my question would be a direct consequence of. However, can we prove this without appealing to this theorem? One idea I had was perhaps using [min-max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) theorem with the standard basis vectors. For instance we know that $$\lambda_1 = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{x^*Mx}{x^*x} \geq \frac{e_1^*Me_1}{e_1^*e_1}= m_{11},$$ (assuming that the diagonal of $M$ is already in nondecreasing order, if not we can do make $PMP^{-1}$ have the desired order for $P$ permutation). Then continue this process and sum up the terms to prove the inequality. Does this work or is something missing?

Edit: What I had in mind was the following:
For $\lambda_2$, we have
$$\lambda_2 = \min_{e_1,e_3,\dots,e_{n-2}} \max_{x \neq 0 \\ x \perp e_i \\ i \neq2} \frac{x^*Mx}{x^*x} \geq \min_{e_1,e_3,\dots,e_{n-2}} \frac{e_2^*Me_2}{e_2^*e_2} = m_{22}.$$ Perhaps this is not legal, but this was my interpretation of the min-max theorem.

Comment: That works for $k=1$, how would you continue?

Comment: $\lambda_k = \min_{u_1 ,\dots, u_{n-k}} \max_{x \neq 0; x \perp u_i} \frac{x^*Mx}{x^*x}$, so can we choose our $u$'s to be the standard basis vectors and show it this way?

Comment: But that min plays badly with picking vectors $e_2$?

Comment: Sorry maybe I just was thinking about it incorrectly but I was thinking that when we choose $x = e_2$, then there would be no dependence of the original choice of $u$'s and so we would get that inequality that way. Perhaps this is not right.

Comment: $x$ has to be perpendicular to the $u$'s, so that would cause issues right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the min-max theorem. I made an edit to convey my idea (which could potentially be wrong).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximize $\mathrm{tr}(Q^TCQ)$ subject to $Q^TQ=I$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637453/maximize-mathrmtrqtcq-subject-to-qtq-i)

Comment: regarding the duplicate tag: take one of the many proofs in that link and consider the special case where $Q$'s columns are standard basis vectors.  You recover your (majorization) result.  I would suggest learning Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing as it is quite flexible and pays many dividends

Comment: @user8675309: Is the Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing equivalent to Poincare Separation Theorem?