# Solution of a minimization problem under Stiefel manifold

Tags: matrices, optimization, trace, stiefel-manifolds

I have the following optimization problem

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{X \in \Bbb R^{n \times c}} \quad &  \operatorname{tr} \left( X^T A X \right) \\
\text { subject to } \quad & X^T X =I_c \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

It is known that the solution is eigenvectors corresponding to the $c$ smallest eigenvalues of $A$. The problem that I have is that $A$ depends on $X$. In this case, I don't know the solution.

Since the problem is a sub-problem of a bigger one, and needs to solve this equation multiple times, hence ($X(t)$, And $A(t)$ are evolving). I found that in a paper, it considers that $A(t)$ dependes not on $X(t)$, but rather  on $X(t-1)$. And thus return to the first problem that is known how to solve. Is this possible? What can we do to justify this approximation?

Note that if it helps, $$A= B_1 + PB_2P +P^{2} X B_3 X^T P^{2}$$
where $B_i$ does not depend on $X$ and $P$ is a diagonal matrix  depends on $X$ !! with

$$P =\operatorname{diag}\left( \left( x_i^T x_i \right)^{-0.5} \right)$$
where $x_i$ is the i-th row of $X$.

Note that $A$ is always symmetric.

Comment: Have you tried using a Lagrange multiplier matrix?

Comment: I was thinking if it mighit exist a closed form solution, if not, if the proposed method in the paper is correct, and why, if not? what are the alternatives, I ddint though of the lAgrange multiplier honeslty.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I don't think that the lagrian will give something, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637453/maximize-mathrmtrqtcq-subject-to-qtq-i/) they tried the same thing on less complicated $A$ with no result.